Why is a Robocopy destination invisible even though it exists?
In Windows 10, I am doing a backup of a drive s:\ to a destination folder (that I did not create) t:\dest with robocopy s:\ t:\dest\ /s (all but empty folders).
The problem is at the end of the operation, the new folder is not visible in explorer or powershell (ls), however, I can cd to it from powershell or explorer.
I tried to create a new folder from explorer dest2, and then rename dest to dest2, or move dest to dest2, the content is still not visible, and it seems was erased, even though, the freespace of the destination drive did not change. I started the robocopy command again, the created folder became unvisible again.
I refreshed explorer, restarted it, without success.
What is happening? How can I make the destination folder visible?

what stops you from doing md t:\dest in the first place? Also, why do you put the wrong slashes in? File paths in windows should use \ not /.

@LPChip I did the command, not need to create the folder. Anyway, even if it was created, it disappeared after the robocopy command. / and \ are equivalent here, no problem, it's just a unix habit.

On at least one of my Windows computers, File Explorer doesn't auto-refresh when new files are added. Have you tried using F5 to force a refresh on an open File Explorer window after using Robocopy?  And while / and \ are equivalent in some cases, does that ensure that they are in ALL situations, particularly to programs (like Robocopy) specifically for parameters?  or tl;dr, have you tried it using / and \ correctly prove that it makes no difference?

@SteveRindsberg I updated the OP. I actually used \ in my command, not /.

When you ran the command, did you see Robocopy echoing anything to the console?

I guess this is some issue with the Robocopy when your Source is the Root.  It just hides the destination folder. Just Unhide it using ATTRIB

I could simulate the same event in Windows 10 VM. See here the animated GIF https://i.imgur.com/KZJ2rHv.gif   Simple ATTRIB -s -h <folder> brings it back. This only happens if your source is the root drive like D:\
